# Gibt es eine Bedeutung des "Kraweel, Kraweel" Gedichts von Lothar Frohwein (Loriot)?

Tags: meaning, poetry

Das in der Lesung des Kulturvereins von Frau Lohse [von Lothar <s>Frohlein</s> Frohwein persönlich verlesene Gedicht](http://youtu.be/ghbj6iNPfCU?t=3m28s) geht so:

> #### Melusine!
>
> Kraweel, Kraweel!
> Taubtrüber Ginst am Musenhain!
> Trübtauber Hain am Musenginst!
> Kraweel, Kraweel!

Für mich, als relativ Gedicht-unzugänglichen Menschen ist das Kauderwelsch und ich habe immer angenommen, dass es keinerlei Bedeutung hat (wenn man mal davon absieht, dass es zum totlachen ist wie Loriot es vorliest).

Ginst scheint mir ein erfundenes Wort zu sein, außer es soll [Ginster](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginster) heißen. Und was ein Musenhain sein soll ist mir auch unklar. Ein Hain in dem eine Muse lebt vielleicht?

Versteckt sich da also irgendwo ein Sinn drin?

Comment: Ich habe noch nie was für Gedicht jeglicher Art übrig gehabt, und wenn ich das lese, weiß ich auch wieder, warum :D Achja... b2t http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_geflügelter_Worte/K#Kraweel.2C_kraweel.21

Comment: achja, [Ginst](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ginst), und es wird wohl Krawehl geschrieben, wobei [Kraweel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraweel) tatsächlich noch ne Bedeutung hätte, wobei fraglich ist, was denn Hain und Ginst mit Schiffen zu tuen haben ;)

Comment: Dazu fallen mir als weitere Hilfsfragen ein: Welches v.d. Kritik geadelte Gedicht hat das gl. Versmaß? Welch ernsthafter Lyriker hat ähnliche Wortbildungen?

Answer (score 22):

Liebe alle, 
ich denke eigentlich schon, dass es sich "Kraweel" schreibt. Das Gedicht hat vielleicht keine tiefere Bedeutung, aber Melusine ist ja eine alte Geschichte, die in vielen Versionen erhalten ist (u.a. in dem erwähnten Prosaroman von Thüring von Ringoltingen). Sie handelt von einer Wasserfrau, die sich mit einem Ritter vermählt. Er darf sie jedoch immer dann nicht sehen, wenn sie sich zurück in ihr Fischwesen verwandelt.

Die Verse von Loriot sind ja nur die Anfangsverse des Gedichts, denn Lothar Frohlein (oder so) wird ja von seinem Schluckauf unterbrochen. Es ist also davon auszugehen, dass das Melusine-Motiv noch weiter ausgebaut würde. Die ersten Verse, so habe ich es immer verstanden, bilden sozusagen das 'Setting': Eine Kraweel ist ja ein mittelalterlicher Schiffstyp, der erste und der vierte Vers verstehen sich also als "Ein Schiff! Ein Schiff!". Dann wird es zugegeben etwas dunkel - immerhin handelt es sich ja um eine Parodie besonders verstiegener, abgelegener Gedichte -, aber 'Ginst' ist durchaus nicht bedeutungslos, sondern heißt, wenn mein Duden recht hat, 'Reisig' oder 'Gestrüpp'. Der Musenhain ist keine häufige Formulierung, aber gemeint ist ein kleiner Garten, in dem man sich zur Diskussion von Dichtung und Kunst trifft, in dem sozusagen die "Musen" leben. Der zweite und dritte Vers bedeuten also "Reisig, der vom Tau noch trüb ist, am Hain der Dichtung". Das hat natürlich mit der Melusine und der Kraweel auf ersten Blick wenig zu tun.

Also: Es handelt sich natürlich um eine Parodie und um ein Nonsense-Gedicht, das zudem ja im Film abgebrochen wird. Aber die einzelnen Elemente tragen alle Bedeutung und beziehen sich aufeinander - Melusine und Kraweel auf die Wasserfrau und ein Schiff -, - Ginst und der Musenhain auf einen Garten oder einen kleinen Wald. Vielleicht ist ein liebliches Ufer gemeint, auf das die Kraweel sich hinbewegt? Vielleicht, um die Melusine abzuholen? Aber das kann man nicht sicher sagen. Ziemlich sicher nur scheint mir, dass es sich "Kraweel" schreibt und dass die Wörter nicht ausgedacht sind. Warum aber der ziemlich unbekannte Arno Schmidt-Herausgeber Ernst Krawehl gemeint sein soll - einmal von der lautlichen Namensähnlichkeit abgesehen - will mir überhaupt nicht einleuchten.

Comment: Sehr gut analyisiert! Vordergründig eine Parodie, eigentlich aber auch ein Tempel für den Lyriker. Das zeigt wieder die Genialität von Loriot.

Answer (score 16):

Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass Loriot bewusst **keine** Bedeutung hinter den Zeilen hatte, da in besagtem Sketch ja gerade die **Unsinnigkeit** der Dichterlesung zum Ausdruck kommen sollte.

Comment: Wenn man davon ausgeht, dass in Gedichten prinzipiell keine platte Bedeutung versteckt ist, die objektiv zu entschlüsseln ist, dann wäre einem gedichtkundigen Menschen durchaus zuzutrauen, dass er Gedichte damit auf die Schippe nimmt, dass er eins produziert, das wie ein solches aussieht, aber eben doch eine Bedeutung hat. Kraweel!

Comment: @userunknown - Ist es ein *Metagedicht*?

Answer (score 6):

In vielen Gedichten entsteht der Sinn erst im Kopf des Lesers. Ich denke, das wird beim vorliegenden Exemplar auch so der Fall sein.

Ich habe vor neun Jahren selbst mal ein Gedicht geschrieben und veröffentlicht, das völlig ohne beabsichten Sinn ist. Ich habe ein ansprechendes Versmaß verwendet und dann Wörter zusammengeklaubt die gut in dieses Schema passen. Die "Sätze" sind nicht mal grammatisch vollständige Sätze, aber das erwartet man von einem Gedicht ohnehin nicht.

Einen Sinn wollte ich damit keineswegs transportieren, dennoch hat es dieses Gedicht ohne mein Zutun auf mindestens zwei Literatur-Seiten im Internet geschafft, wo dann (ohne mich dazu zu befragen) darüber diskutiert wurde, wie den nun die Zefire, die in Strophe 2 vorkommen, in Hinblick auf die Einfalt, die in Strophe 3 vorkommt, zu deuten seien.

Link zum Gedicht auf meiner Website: http://hubert.schoelnast.at/texte/text/nebel.html
Das was wirklich dahintersteckte: http://hubert.schoelnast.at/texte/info/nebel.info.html

Comment: "Gewöhnlich glaubt der Mensch, wenn er nur Worte hört,
Es müsse sich dabei doch auch was denken lassen."
 ― Mephistopheles/Goethe

Comment: @celtschk: Wenn man nicht auf den Kopf gefallen ist lässt sich auch tatsächlich regelmäßig etwas dazu denken.

Comment: Fast auf den Spuren von  Eduard Mörike "Er ist's" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Im Internet gibt es verschiedene Hinweise auf dieses Gedicht von Loriot, wobei sich die Schreibweise von "Kraweel" unterscheidet:

- [Kraweel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/K#Kraweel.2C_kraweel.21) (mit Verweis auf den Dichter Peter Handke)
- [Krawehl](http://www.an-sylvia.de/krawehl.htm) (mit Verweis auf den Dichter Peter Handke)
- [Krawehl](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme73/article6086050.html) (mit Verweis auf den Dichter Trakl und den Herrn Ernst Krawehl)
- [Ernst Krawehl](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Krawehl) (Verleger, Verlagslektor von Arno Schmidt; Verweis auf Loriot unter "Sonstiges")

Daraus schließe ich, dass "Krawehl" die richtige Schreibweise ist und Loriot sich hier auf Ernst Krawehl bezieht.

"Melusine" scheint der Name des ersten "Prosaromans" zu sein (Verweis auf erstes Gedicht?).

Mir entzieht sich die Kenntnis, ob Loriot einen der beiden Dichter Handke oder Trakl besonders geschätzt oder abgelehnt hat, aber ich denke, zusammen ergibt sich ein stimmiges Bild dieser genialen Parodie von Dichterlesungen, erfrischende "Respektlosigkeit" des Bürgertums und der Ratlosigkeit, die manche Werke hinterlassen ...

Comment: Krawehl muss nicht die einzige richtige Schreibweise sein, Kraweel ist ein Schiffstyp: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraweel und https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beplankung . Aber Loriot hat wohl einfach ein möglichst seltenes Wort gesucht.

Comment: Im Buch ist es Kraweel... was andererseits nicht heißt, dass das nicht eine leicht verfremdete Schreibung für Krawehl ist..

Answer (score 2):

Mit *Kraweel* dürfte weder die Karavelle noch eine Person gemeint sein, eher der Lautklang eines Raben, der die Einleitung zum Drama bildet, daher am Ende noch einmal wiederholt. Der Rabe würde im weiteren Verlauf wohl als
"Erzähler", der von außen auf die vorgetragene Geschichte blickt, weiter eine Rolle haben. Dies ist eine oft benutzte Form. Dazu passt auch der Musenhain, in dem der Rabe sitzt und in die Erzählung einführt.

Das Gedicht hat ebenfalls sicherlich keinen Bezug zu einem einzelnen anderen Gedicht, sondern veräppelt in seiner Bedeutungs(un)schwere das lyrische Drama an sich.

Btw. wie Leute versuchen, eine Bedeutung im Namen Kraweel auszumachen, zeigt die Genialität Loriots, dessen Absicht wohl genau dies war.

Auch das Vertauschen einzelner Wortbilder in der Wiederholung macht beim Raben, der die menschliche Sprache herauskrakeelt, durchaus Sinn im Unsinn.

Also haben wir es hier mit einem Raben zu tun, der in einem Musenhain Reime vorkrakeelt über das Drama der Melusine. Genial.

Das Wort Kraweel dürfte so entstanden sein: "Krakeelen... Krakeel... Kraweel, Kraweel, der Rabe krakeelt", eine nette Wortspielerei daher auch die dunkle Lederjacke und das Herauskrakeelen der Verse im Vortrag. Loriot war Perfektionist. Unschwer sich einen Raben vorzustellen, der sein Gefieder herausputzt.

Die Dissonanz des epischen Bildes eines Raben, der ein Drama im Musenhain vorträgt, mit dem Dichter, der in seinem Vortrag an dem Kohlrabi mit Dauerschluckauf scheitert, macht letztlich die Szene völlig lächerlich.

Ich denke, dass wir unterbewusst die Bilder verarbeiten und deswegen so lachen müssen bei dieser Szene, selbst ohne bewusst die Bedeutung zu wissen. Und das ist Kunst in höchster Form.

(Mir ist das Alter des Threads bewusst sowie dass dies eine eigene subjektive Interpretation ist.)

Answer (score 2):

> Versteckt sich da also irgendwo ein Sinn drin?

Die Antwort liegt beim Leser bzw. Hörer. Die einzelnen Worte des Gedichts sind durchaus wohlklingend, obschon nicht im Duden zu finden und weitgehend sinnfrei. Allerdings animieren sie dazu, über mögliche Bedeutungen nachzudenken, und das führt immerhin zu einer Runde "Gehirnjogging".

Der Mensch neigt dazu, auch im völlig Chaotischen und Zufälligen Muster zu erkennen - oder eben im Unfug tiefere Bedeutungen zu sehen. Wer hat nicht schon am Himmel Wolken in Form von Tieren gesehen? Auch manche Verschwörungstheorie dürfte auf der Erkennung von vermeintlichen Mustern beruhen.

In der Tradition von Loriots Gedicht sehe ich Hape Kerkelings [Hurz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ7jbQJXF68)-Performance. Wer das nicht kennt, sollte den beigefügten Link öffnen. Das Spektrum der Wissenschaft spricht sogar vom [Hurz-Effekt](https://www.spektrum.de/magazin/der-hurz-effekt/1695902). Zitat:

> Denn das wirklich Witzige an diesem Sketch [...] ist nicht etwa der miserabelst vorgetragene Nonsense vom Lämmlein und dem Wolf auf der grünen Wiese, sondern der Versuch des Publikums, dieser Albernheit Sinn und künstlerischen Wert beizumessen.

Ein möglicherweise noch schöneres Beispiel ist der Artikel

> [The conceptual penis as a social construct](https://www.skeptic.com/downloads/conceptual-penis/23311886.2017.1330439.pdf)

der 2017 in der Zeitschrift *Cogent Social Sciences* erschien. Dass es sich um Parodie handelte, fiel wohl keinem der Referees auf. Immerhin sind hier aber alle Sätze klar verständlich, der Nonsense ist nicht schon auf sprachlicher Ebene erkennbar wie bei Loriot, sondern  wird erst auf der inhaltlichen Ebene deutlich. Oder eben auch nicht - vielleicht haben die Autoren ja unabsichtlich tiefe Wahrheiten enthüllt?

Siehe auch [hier](https://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/phl_fac/29/).

Answer (score 1):

2.Zeile: "Taubtrüber Ginst am Musenhain!"

3.Zeile: "Trübtauber Hain am Musenginst!"

Die 3. Zeile des Gedichts entsteht aus der 2. Zeile durch Vertauschen der Wörter "taub" und "trüb" sowie der Wörter "Ginst" und "Hain".

Das deutet darauf hin, dass es Nonsens sein soll, ohne jeden tieferen Sinn.

Comment: Wieso deutet es darauf hin? Dass die Zeilen ähnlich sind ist klar, aber was ist die Aussage für die anderen Wörter? Es ist gängig in Gedichten solche Vertauschungen zu machen (das ist ja der Witz).

Comment: Vertauschungen in Gedichten sind kein zwingender Hinweis auf Nonsens. Z.B.: »Ein Tor singt jede Liederweise, / 
zuweilen laut, dann wieder leise. / 
Dagegen gibt der Weise Lieder, / 
die er nicht kennt, nur leise wieder.«

Answer (score 1):

Kraweel oder Krawehl ist der Mittelwert von "Krawall" und "krakeelen" und daher wahrscheinlich eine ganz bewusste Schöpfung/Fuegung zum Zweck der Parodie des Kunstbetriebs im taubtrueb verginsteten Musenhain der damaligen Bundesrepublik.

(In der Wikipedia wird das Gedicht inzwischen als Parodie auf Georg Trakls Gedichtästhetik behandelt.)

Answer (score 0):

Nein, Freunde...
Kennt denn hier keiner "Iphigenie auf Tauris" von Goethe? Das ist ein Drama angelehnt an den griechischen Ursprung der Dramen. Die Urfassung ist auch von solch Kauderwelsch durchwachsen und ich denke, es handelt sich lediglich um eine Parodie eben dieses Werkes.

Comment: Möchtest Du diese Vermutung in irgend einer Form durch Belege untermauern, oder ist das bloß Deine subjektive Meinung?

Comment: Was ist eine nicht-subjektive Meinung?

Answer (score 0):

Für mich wird hier einfach auf lustige Weise ein vertrottelter Literaturspinner auf die Schippe genommen und mit seinem gesamten Habitus entzaubert. Seine Klamotten knirschen, er kriegt Schluckauf, muss gestehen, dass er am Abend zuvor vulgären Kohlrabi und Fischstäbchen gefressen hat und die Zuhörer machen sich weniger über seine »Werke«, sondern über seinen Schluckauf Gedanken: »Man müsste ihn erschrecken ...«

Comment: Wieso ist Kohlrabi vulgär? Davon ab, wie beantwortet das die Frage?

Answer (score 0):

Die Melusine ist ein Fabelwesen, üblicher Gestalt einer Frau, die sich jedoch teilweise als Frau mit Schlangenleib manifestiert. Der Geliebte / Gatte / Angetraute darf jedoch diese Gestalt nicht erblicken, auf dass grosses Ungemach über beide heranbricht.

Krawehl: Segelschiff besser als Karebelle bekannt (Ja, die Dinger mit denen Kolumbus nach Amerika gesegelt ist halt)

Ginst: Veraltete Bezeichnung für Reisig.

Zum Hain und zur Muse muss ich wohl weiter nichts sagen, zu Taub und Trüb wohl auch nicht.

Comment: Die Art der Beplankung heisst aber Kraweel statt Krawehl. Die Schiffe von Columbus hiessen Karavelle. Karebelle ist vermutlich Unsinn.